# Prove that the roots of $g(x)$ are also real

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics, discriminant

> Suppose there are two equations $$f(x)=x^2+bx+c=0$$ and $$g(x)=x^2+bx+c(x+a)(2x+b)=0$$
> It is given that $f(x)$ has two real roots. Then prove that $g(x)$ also has two real roots when $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

My work:

$$g(x)=x^2(2c+1)+x(b+bc+2ac)+abc=0$$
$$\Delta g(x)=(b+bc+2ac)^2-4(2c+1)(abc)$$
$$=b^2+b^2c^2+4a^2c^2+2b^2c-4abc^2$$
Now we have to prove that $b^2+b^2c^2+4a^2c^2+2b^2c-4abc^2\ge0$ or $b^2c-2abc^2\ge0$

The only information we have is that $b^2-4c\ge0$ or $b^2c\ge4c^2$ or $$b^2c-2abc^2\ge 4c^2-2abc^2$$ I can't continue from here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** I just saw a counter example to this question. But let's suppose that $a\ge \frac {b}2$. Will it be true in that case$?$

Comment: I don't see how you derive that $c^2$. I bet there's an error in the computations

Comment: @Exodd where$?$ can you pls point out

Comment: when you square the first term in the $\Delta$ it should be $b^2c^2$, not $c^2$

Comment: @Exodd corrected thanks

Comment: but the question remains the same

Comment: Hint: you can see the formula as a function in $a$. It is a parabola, so you can compute its minimum and show that the minimum is nonnegative

Comment: @Exodd can you pls write the formula that you indicated$?$

Comment: There are so many to deal with

Comment: There is still misprint with $c^2$. I believe correct problem statement must look $f(x)=0$ has two complex non-real roots.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I strongly believe that it was written **real roots** nevertheless I'll rectify

Comment: $\Delta=b^2+b^2c^2+4a^2c^2+2b^2c-4abc^2=(2ac-bc)^2+b^2(2c+1)$. If $c$ is bounded from above (as follows from $b^2-4c\geq 0$), then there is no lower limit for $\Delta$. For $\Delta$ to be positive at any $c$, one needs $c$ to be bounded from below. $b^2-4c < 0$ leads to $c > b^2/4 \geq 0$ , then $\Delta \geq 0$.

Comment: Note this seems true when $a,b,c>0$ as the minimum for $g$ seems to always be lower than the minimum of $f$ graphically.

Comment: Claim from problem statement is true when $c\geq -\frac{1}{2}$ at any real $a$ and $b$. At any $c<-\frac{1}{2}$ there are real $a$ and $b$ such that $\Delta < 0$, $b^2-4c\geq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true or there are conditions missing on $a,b,c$.

Take $b=1$ and $c=-2$ then $f(x)=x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x+2)$ has two real roots.

While $g(x)=3x^2+(4a+1)x+2a$ has discriminant $\Delta=16a^2-16a+1$ which can be negative.

For instance for $a=\frac 12$.

Comment: Yes, I was about to write it. Also, $a=1, b=2, c=-1$ is another conterexample

Comment: Well done (you were fast)! Easy to find counterexamples. Mine was $b=2,a=1$, $c=-1000$ or some such.

Answer (score 2):

$$b^2+b^2c^2+4a^2c^2+2b^2c-4abc^2$$
$$\ge b^2+b^2c^2+4(\frac{b}{2})^2c^2+2b^2c-4\frac{b}{2}bc^2$$
$$=b^2(1+2c)$$
So it is true only for $c>-\dfrac{1}{2}$.

**EDIT** If $c=-\dfrac{1}{2}$ then $g(x)=x(\dfrac{b}{2}-a)-\dfrac{ab}{2}=0$ has less than two roots. Thanks @zwim!

Comment: $a\ge b/2$ cannot be replaced by $-a\ge -b/2$ in the last term.

Comment: @zwim: I believe second line is value at minimum of parabola, which is exactly at $a=b/2$.

Comment: Note that for $c=-\frac 12$ then $g$ is degenerated into a straight line, so we don't have a root of multiplicity $2$ but only one.